# How can I clear the buffer？

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, bytebuffer

I have written a class which can recieve texts from the Bluetooth Serial Port, but when I sent “a” it toast “akkk” after I sent “kkkk” it toast “kkkk”, why should it's result beyound the consideration？What should I do to make it toast “a”？Can I clear the buffer, and how？

Here is my code:

```
class RecieveThread extends Thread {   
 private final InputStream mmInStream;
 @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR)
 protected RecieveThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream(); 
        } catch (IOException ignored) { }
        mmInStream = tmpIn;
    } 
 public void run() {
        Looper.prepare();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; 
        int bytes; 
        while (true) {     
            try {       
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer); 
                String str = new String(buffer);
                handler.obtainMessage(READ, bytes, -1, str)
                    .sendToTarget();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                s=e.getMessage();
                System.out.print(s);
                h=false;
                break;
            }
        }
        Looper.loop(); 
    }    
}

Handler handler = new Handler() { 
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        if (msg.what==READ) {
            String str = (String)msg.obj;
            Toast.makeText(MyService.this,msg.str+"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if(h==false)
            Toast.makeText(MyService.this,"Failed："+s+".",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer); 
String str = new String(buffer);
```

Usual problem. You're ignoring the count.

```
bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer); 
String str = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
```